# My Flutter project isn't running (Error Message)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I received the following error running flutter.
The error seems to be from the package [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

Compiler message:

```
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dio-2.2.2/lib/src/dio_http_headers.dart:55:8: Error: The method 'DioHttpHeaders.add' has fewer named
arguments than those of overridden method 'HttpHeaders.add'.
  void add(String name, value) {                                        
       ^                                                                
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/_http/http.dart:694:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('add').
  void add(String name, Object value,                                   
       ^                                                                
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dio-2.2.2/lib/src/dio_http_headers.dart:70:8: Error: The method 'DioHttpHeaders.set' has fewer named
arguments than those of overridden method 'HttpHeaders.set'.
  void set(String name, Object value) {                                 
       ^                                                                
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/_http/http.dart:703:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('set').
  void set(String name, Object value,
```

This is what i was trying to implement

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_rave/flutter_rave.dart';

class DepositPage extends StatefulWidget {
  DepositPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _DepositPageState createState() => _DepositPageState();
}

class _DepositPageState extends State<DepositPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: Builder(
      builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () => _pay(context),
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
              elevation: 15,
              child: Container(
                height: 250,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Center(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Card Payment",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.payment,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        size: 30,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }

  _pay(BuildContext context) {
    final snackBar_onFailure = SnackBar(content: Text('Transaction failed'));
    final snackBar_onClosed = SnackBar(content: Text('Transaction closed'));
    final _rave = RaveCardPayment(
      isDemo: true,
      encKey: "i have to hide this",
      publicKey: "i have to hide this too",
      transactionRef: "This as well",
      amount: 100,
      email: "demo1@example.com",
      onSuccess: (response) {
        print("$response");
        print("Transaction Successful");
        if (mounted) {
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text("Transaction Sucessful!"),
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              duration: Duration(
                seconds: 5,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
      onFailure: (err) {
        print("$err");
        print("Transaction failed");
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar_onFailure);
      },
      onClosed: () {
        print("Transaction closed");
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar_onClosed);
      },
      context: context,
    );
    _rave.process();
  }
}
```

I was trying to implement payment in my app using flutter wave.
Currently i'm using Dart 2.8.4 and Flutter 1.17.5
I already ran flutter clean but that didn't do anything
would appreciate some help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to a newer version in the pubspec.yaml (only in GitHub's author)

```
flutter_rave:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/demimola24/flutter_rave.git
      ref: master
```